# Downloading Image from firebase only works once in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am uploading image to `firebase` storage in my main activity and showing that image in my `recyclerview`. After clicking on image in my `recycler` view,i am moving to `fullimageactivity` and passing `url` of that image.
Below is the code for `fullimageactivity` which has a button and on click of it,i am downloading the image to user's phone

```
public class FullImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    Button button;
    private static final int WATER_REMINDER_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1138;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimageactivityimageview);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("Image");
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).into(imageView);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            ) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                    }

                } else {
                    downloadImage();

                }
            }});

    }


    private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... URL) {
            Bitmap bitmapimage = null;
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {
                bitmapimage = Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(URL[0]).asBitmap().into(100, 100).get();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmapimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmapimage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        }


    }

    private PendingIntent contentIntent(Context context) {

        //  Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image")));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));

        PendingIntent contentIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        id,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        return contentIntent;
    }

    private Bitmap largeIcon(Context context) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.notification);
        return largeIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                downloadImage();
            }

        }
    }

    public void downloadImage() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new DownloadImage().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("Image"));
        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon(getApplicationContext()))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.imagedownloaded))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent(getApplicationContext()))
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(WATER_REMINDER_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

When i click download button for first time,image is downloaded properly.When i go back to my `mainactivity` and choose different image and click on it,i move to `fullimageactivity` and on click of button of `fullimageactivity` image won't download.
In short it downloads only the first image and then it won't download any more image.Please help me with what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device is contain marshmello then this issue will be create because in your first time you are request for permission, but once permission is granted then second time downloadimage() is not call , so edit your code like below :

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        ) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                }else {
                downloadImage();
            } else {
                downloadImage();

            }
```